# Spring Boot Starter dependency for logstash

Tags: spring-boot

For logging  we have **spring-boot-starter-logging** similarly instead of using direct depedency as shown in image, does spring boot provide any **starter dependency**?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J8Pw.png)

Comment: I'm struggling to make sense of your question, please can you clarify? Also if you are including code it's always best to include the code as a code snippet not an image.

Comment: @Popeye My question was that does spring boot provide any starter dependency for net.logstash.logback?